# Does the result $Ind_{H}^{G}Res_{H}^{G}N\approx\mathbb{Z}[G/H]\otimes N$ hold for $\mathbb{Q}$?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory

pp. 69 prop 5.6 of Brown's Cohomology of groups states that $Ind_{H}^{G}Res_{H}^{G}N\approx\mathbb{Z}[G/H]\otimes N$. Would this hold for $\mathbb{Q}$ and if so does anyone know a reference or is there a simple reason why that I'm missing?

Comment: Inducing a representation from a subgroup involves (depending on your definition of induction) functions on the space $G/H$, so it is fairly natural to expect that you'll get $G/H$ "copies of" the original representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The representation $\mathbf{Z}[G/H]$ is the induced representation $$\mathbf{Z}[G/H]=\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbf{Z}[H]}^{\mathbf{Z}[G]}(1),$$ where we write $1$ for the trivial representation. Using the *projection formula* in the form
$$\mathrm{Ind}(\mathrm{Res}(N) \otimes P) \cong N \otimes \mathrm{Ind}(P)$$ for $P=1$ then gives the result you are asking for. So the result is valid in any context in which the projection formula holds, and for which the permutation representation on the cosets of $H$ in $G$ is induced from the trivial representation.