# Why does $\mathbb{Z}[G/H]=\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{Z}[H]}^{\mathbb{Z}[G]}(1)$ hold?

Tags: algebraic-topology, representation-theory

Why does  $\mathbb{Z}[G/H]=\mathrm{Ind}_{\mathbb{Z}[H]}^{\mathbb{Z}[G]}(1)$ where 1 denotes the trivial representation hold? Can anyone help with a proof or reference?

Comment: By $\mathbf{Z}$ do you mean the integers? And equality as what?

Comment: Have edited it so it's clear it's the integers. I don't really understand your other question, what I have written is what I was informed was true but I want to know why.

Comment: But usually $\mathbb{Z}[G]$ would mean the group algebra, except that $G/H$ might not be a group, and you are inducing a representation. Does the left hand side refer to the integral representation of $G$ on the $\mathbb{Z}$-span of $G/H$ and acting by left translation?

Comment: This is the context in which it was being used: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475051/does-the-result-ind-hgres-hgn-approx-mathbbzg-h-otimes-n-hold-fo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the context of

[Does the result $Ind_{H}^{G}Res_{H}^{G}N\approx\mathbb{Z}[G/H]\otimes N$ hold for $\mathbb{Q}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2475051/does-the-result-ind-hgres-hgn-approx-mathbbzg-h-otimes-n-hold-fo)

the notation $\mathbf{Z}[G/H]$ is shorthand for the $\mathbf{Z}G$-module with $\mathbf{Z}$-basis the cosets $gH$ for $g \in G$, and with $G$-action defined by left multiplication
$$g\cdot g'H=gg'H \quad \hbox{for $g,g' \in G$.}$$

By definition the induced representation $\mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbf{Z}G}_{\mathbf{Z}H}(1)$ is
$$\mathrm{Ind}^{\mathbf{Z}G}_{\mathbf{Z}H}(1)=\mathbf{Z}G \otimes_{\mathbf{Z}H} \mathbf{Z},$$ where we write $\mathbf{Z}$ for the $\mathbf{Z}H$-module which is isomorphic to $\mathbf{Z}$ as an abelian group, and on which every element of $H$ acts by the identity.

One defines a $\mathbf{Z}H$-balanced map
$$\mathbf{Z}G \times \mathbf{Z} \rightarrow \mathbf{Z}[G/H] \quad \text{by the formula} \quad \left(\sum c_g g,m \right) \mapsto \sum mc_g gH$$ and checks that it induces the desired isomorphism of $\mathbf{Z}G$-modules.

Comment: Would $\mathrm{Ind}_{H}^{G}(\mathbb{Z})$ be the same thing then?

Comment: @Rhoswyn The notation $1$ as I have used it means the trivial representation; in the context of $\mathbf{Z} G$-module it is the same thing as $\mathbf{Z}$. So yes, here $\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(\mathbf{Z})=\mathrm{Ind}_H^G(1)$.

Comment: (I am sometimes too pedantic about the base ring, which is why I wrote $\mathbf{Z} G$ in my answer).